# Install documentation to a package in Mathematica 13

Tags: packages

I am trying to use the [sneg](http://nrgljubljana.ijs.si/sneg/) package in Mathematica 13. It seems to work (tested some examples), but the documentation is inaccessible.
I installed the package to `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/sneg`, so the documentation is in `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/sneg/Documentation/English` and consists of a bunch of `.nb` files. I am aware of [earlier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21307/how-can-i-get-mathematica-to-recognize-the-documentation-for-a-newly-installed-p) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220069/how-can-i-install-sneg-library-package-on-windows), but they do not seem to apply for Mathematica 13 anymore. For example, there is no longer a `Rebuild Help Index` button, and in `Help->Wolfram Documentation->Add-ons and Packages` there is no add-on listed (which is strange, I can use the sneg examples just fine in any arbitrary directory, as long as I keep the diagonalize.m file close by). Any suggestions how I properly install the sneg package including documentation?

Comment: Have you contacted the package developer about this? More than likely, they can help you solve this issue the proper way.

Comment: I have not contacted the developer yet. They only advertise compatibility to Mathematica 11.3. I will contact if someone can confirm that installing packages in Mathematica 13 is still in the directories I listed. Especially the documentation. I think something has changed in Mathematica 13, because the package itself works fine, just the documentation does not.

Comment: I agree that this question should go directly to the developer.